# WMI query, get local info from remote server (for BgInfo)

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, wmi

I'm using [BgInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/bginfo) on a Windows server that users remotely connect to via RDP. BgInfo allows you to create custom elements based on WMI queries. I'd like to show the user's local hostname or IP address. Is there a WMI class that contains the remotely connected user's local hostname? Otherwise, is there another one-step way in BgInfo to get this information?

Comment: Like this: `wmic.exe /node:"IP-or-HostName" ComputerSystem Get UserName` ?

Comment: The result is only a column heading that says "UserName". The intended query will be run from the sever the user is remotely connected to, and should return the user's local hostname.

Comment: So you are basically asking for the hostname of the user on his own computer, but doing that from his RDP session on the server computer. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT IP is acceptable in place of hostname. WMI is the preferred solution as it is one of the few sources for custom values that BgInfo offers. BgInfo does have other source options, like "Contents of a file", but I'd like to avoid needing multiple steps to reach this solution if at all possible (eg Powershell run externally with results saved to file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a WMI solution but simpler, if you would run following script on the server while connected over RDP, you will obtain hostname of remote computer connected over RDP

```
@echo off

echo %CLIENTNAME%

exit
```

You actually don't need any script since `bginfo` allows to use custom field.
Go to custom fields->add new field and choose `Environment variable` and add variable = `CLIENTNAME`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, WMI cannot do this.
You will need to use Win32 API, in PowerShell for example, and call
directly the
[WTSQuerySessionInformation function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsquerysessioninformationa)
found inside `wtsapi32.dll`, using the parameters:

```
hServer = WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE (null or 0)
SessionId = WTS_CURRENT_SESSION (-1)
```

You can find a working PowerShell example for calling
`WTSQuerySessionInformation`
in this [serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/342533/wmi-object-to-get-current-sessions-with-client-name),
which should get you started.

The item you want to retrieve is `WTSClientName` from the
[_WTS_INFO_CLASS Enumeration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wtsapi32/ne-wtsapi32-_wts_info_class),
containing "A null-terminated string that contains the name of the client",
meaning the name of the client computer.
How to get it is also demonstrated in the above example.